# Download closed Google Sheets by link

Tags: python, google-sheets, download, request, gspread

I have Google Sheets, which only a few people have access to, the link is also closed, so I can't download a document using a regular download link:

```
def download_xlsx():
    url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetID/export?format=xlsx'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'table.xlsx')
```

I realized that the problem is that there is no access to the document by link, I cannot open this access, since the terms of reference are exactly that.
Maybe someone has already faced a similar task and will be able to suggest a solution?

Comment: If you don't have access to the sheet or you don't have permission to download the sheet (as viewer or commenter) then you can't download it.

Comment: @Marios, I have permissions, I can download this document, but I need a download link to get it in my program

Comment: Then your problem is not reproducible because I can use the `url` structure you provided to download the document from the browser and it works perfectly fine. How do **you** use this url to download the file? You mentioned something about a `program`. If you try to use a script to download the excel file based on this url then [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65990739/edit) your question to provide more details and also have a tour on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't debug a code if we don't see it. So a code could be a good start.

Comment: @Marios, edited the question. I think that if you close access to the document by the link, and also try to use the above url, then you will not be able to download the file either. Previously, I already downloaded in this way, but the link was open. I'm sure there are ways to download a document without public access.

Comment: @Polyarniik not using a simple HTTP request without authorisation you can't. If the file isn't public then you need to use the API to download the file, authenticating as a user that has access to the file. You can't just download a document without public access unless you tell Google that you have the right to access the file. Check out [the API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).